# Do I need to buy a developer certificate if inside developer team organization (enrollment)?

Tags: ios

Do I need to buy a indiviudual developer certificate if I'm on the development team of an organization and want to publish and test applications on behalf of the organization.
I do not have my own certificate and I can not test the application on a real device, I indicate that I am inside the team of the organization from which the certificate was purchased.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you do not need to purchase an individual certificate; you develop under the organization's certificate, and release under the organization's certificate as well. In XCode, under the `General` tab, look for the `Signing` section, where you can specify your `Team` (organization). The application will be signed with the organization's certirficate.

Do note, however, that an 'Organization' developer certificate **cannot** publish apps to the Apple App Store, only in-house. If you want to publish to the App Store, you need an 'Enterprise' certificate. If you want to publish both to the store **and** in-house, you'll need **both** certificates!

[image: Apple memberships]

**Also**, note that not only do you need to be a team member of your organization in Apple's Developer Program, but **also** in **[iTunes Connect](https://itunesconnect.apple.com/)**! Those are separate registrations, and you will **[need to be invited](https://help.apple.com/itunes-connect/developer/#/dev300c2c5bf)** to join the iTunes Connect team by the person who set up the team account, or an existing administrator:

> Initially, only the team agent (the person who joins the Apple Developer Program) can sign in to iTunes Connect and perform these steps. [...] If you are the team agent, use the Apple ID you used to join the Apple Developer Program and add other users to your iTunes Connect organization.

You'll need to be in both teams before being able to sign applications with your organization's certificate.

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Tell me please, but in xcode I need to be authorized only by my AppleID without authorization of the admin team?
When I join the team I have different teamID - mine before joining the team and my after, which one to use? IPhone Developer (47IDT2731US) something like this.